# AngularJs Controller is not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, controllers

```js
var loginModule = angular.module("loginModule", ['ngRoute']);


loginModule.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/LoginCredential', {
            templateUrl: 'login_credential.html',
            controller: ''
        }).
        when('/SecurityQuestionPage', {
            templateUrl: 'security_question.html',
            controller: ''
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/LoginCredential'
        });
  }]);


var loginCredController = loginModule.controller('loginCredController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    debugger;
    $scope.loginData = {};
    $scope.submit = function (LoginForm, loginData)
    {
        debugger;
        var uname = loginData.username;
        var pwd = loginData.password;
        var lData = 'username='+uname+'&'+'password='+pwd

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:53738/Login?response_type=code&client_id=peopleworks&redirect_uri=google.com",
            data: lData
        });

        request.success(
            function (response) {
                debugger;
                

            }
        );
    }
}]);
```

this is login.js file. these are my views login.html and login_credential.html

**login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Peopleworks/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Peopleworks/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Peopleworks/Lib/peopleworksLogin.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="loginModule">
            <div ng-view=""></div>
            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and
 **login_credential.html**

```html
<div data-ng-controller ="loginCredController">
<table>
                <form method="post" name="LoginForm" ng-submit="submit(LoginForm, loginData)" novalidate>
                    <tr><td>Username</td><td><input id="username" name="username" ng-model="loginData.username"  type="text" /></td>
                    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input id="password" name="password" ng-model="loginData.password"  type="password" /></td>
                    <tr><td><button type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
</table>
</div>
```

problem is when I click submit the method in controller is not working... can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have html markup wrong. Try closing tr and td tags properly and move form tag out of table tag in such a way that table reside inside form not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

No need of "`var loginCredController=`"

Simple use :-

```
loginModule.controller('loginCredController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Comment: No errors.. I m debuging it.. when I click "submit" it should go to the "loginCredController" and debugger point inside "submit" function should be hit. problem is it doesn't hit. no errors too..

Answer (score 0):

From angularjs docs [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

> You can use one of the following two ways to specify what JavaScript method should be called when a form is submitted:
>
> 1. `ngSubmit` directive on the form element
> 2. `ngClick` directive on the first button or input field of type submit (`input[type=submit]`)
>      To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of the `ngSubmit` or `ngClick` directives.

This is because of the following form submission rules in the HTML specification:

> - If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (`ngSubmit`)
> - if a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or `input[type=submit]` then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
> - if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or `input[type=submit]` (`ngClick`) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (`ngSubmit`)

**Note that `ngClick` events will occur before the model is updated. Use `ngSubmit` to have access to the updated model.**

Use either `ng-submit` or `input[type=submit]`.

Comment: yes.. Here I have use ng-submit as you see. the problem is when I hit the "Login" button it doesn't hit the debugger point in "loginCredController" controller. I'm debugging it in Chrome.. Any reason?

Comment: Can you create fiddle or plnkr of your code? It is really easy to debug and solve the error. Please create and tell me the URL.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lasaluduwara/jypg3592/  this is the link I added two html files in the same section.. you may not messup..